# Moving UserDefaults to an array

Tags: arrays, swift, userdefaults

I'm running into an issue while attempting to move a user defaults array into a second array so I may be able to load it into a table view.

my userdefault is just a single field of type Int. I'm able to store data in the UD and when I display it it shows optional values:
`[176, 177]`

I have the following declared at the top level of my view:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   
var intArray = [[Int:Any]]()
```

In viewDidLoad I have the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      intArray = defaults.array(forKey: "Favorites") as? [[Int: Any]] ?? []
      print(defaults.array(forKey: "Favorites"))
   }
```

The intArray is always empty but when I print the Favorites UserDefault it shows as it does above.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right now, you're trying to decode an array of Dictionaries with `Int` as a key and `Any` as a value (the outer brackets is the array, the inner brackets with the `:` is the dictionary). If you replace `[[Int:Array]]` with `[Int]` does it work?

Comment: No, it shows the same o intArray [[Int]] 0 values

Comment: Still looks like you have an additional set of brackets in what you just commented. Can you show *exactly* what the console says when you do the `print` of the current code? Right now you're saying `optional values: [176, 177]`, which I know isn't *exactly* what it says.

Comment: Are you expecting `intArray` to have some data model like {1: "One"}. Can you post your expected data sample for `intArray`

Comment: My bad, yes I left the extra set of brackets in.  Taking them out fixes the issue.  jnpdx make your suggestion an answer and I'll be happy to give you the credit for it.  Everyone else thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to decode an array of Dictionaries with `Int` as a key and `Any` as a value (the outer set of brackets is the array, the inner brackets with the `:` is the `Dictionary`).

If you replace all occurrences of `[[Int:Array]]` with `[Int]`, your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the reads and writes to `UserDefaults` using a convenient extension like this.

```
import Foundation

extension UserDefaults {
    var favorites: [Int] {
        get { self.array(forKey: #function) as? [Int] ?? [] }
        set { self.set(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }
}
```

In case you have old data stored in your app and you don't want to delete it, you can simply replace `#function` in above `get` / `set` with your key `"Favorites"`.

Here's how you can use above storage -

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.favorites = [1,2,3,4,5] // save

let favorites = defaults.favorites // read
print(favorites) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Store value to User default**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set([1, 2, 3], forKey: "TestArrayUD")
print(UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "TestArrayUD")) // Give Optional array eg: Optional([1, 2, 3])
```

**Read without optional value**

One way is to use `UserDefaults.standard.array` as shown in the example below

```
    if let _intArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "TestArrayUD") {
        print(_intArray) // Eg: [1, 2, 3]
    }
```